# Can you deploy a rails application from any virtual machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

My question is, in essence, given a virtual machine (say with Ubuntu 14.04), can you deploy a rails app. Regardless of who hosts that machine?

I mainly ask this question because I'd like to host a rails application through Google's Cloud Compute Engine VMs. Will google's cloud compute allow me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Google Cloud Appengine is not a VM. You probably talking about Google Cloud Instances or Google Cloud Containers?

Comment: Ok, I see. The answer: yes, it will allow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Compute Engine is not limiting you, as it Appengine does. It's a traditional VM and you can run there whatever you want. You can get an Ubuntu VM and install any software supported by this OS

If you looking for Ruby/Rails, there is an even official "click-to-deploy" VM: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/ruby/. But of course you can setup ruby stack using plain Ubuntu, etc

Comment: If you wouldn't mind answering a follow up: Am I able to install and run a postgresql database on the VM or do I need to use something like amazon RDS to connect my production database to?

Comment: you can install anything supported by underlying OS, including Postgres. So if your OS is Ubuntu, for example, you can install Postgres here

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One of the benefits of using a VM is being able to spin it up on different machines without too much additional configuration.